# How can I exec shell scripts from within a Gatling simulation?

Tags: scala, gatling

I want to add a scenario that runs in parallel to my main http-based scenarios to introduce errors into the environment (by deleting application instances etc.)

I can't see a way to do this from Gatling.  What I want is something that looks a little like this:

```
exec({
  "chaos.sh" !
}).pause(10)
.exec({
  "firewallService.sh enable" !
})
```

etc.

Is this possible with Gatling?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to this problem that avoids trying to write a custom Action and ActionBuilder. It boils down to putting it within a code block elsewhere, like a session builder element:

```
exec(session => {
  val scriptOutput = "/My/Chaos/Script.sh".!!
  println(s"""Chaos invoked: ${scriptOutput} """)
  session
})
```

I picked this because it keeps the test simple, and because all the examples I found for actually writing Actions etc. used Gatling code that had since been refactored. There doesn't seem to be an up-to-date documentation page for this feature

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't seem to compile. Where do you have ".!!" ? Can I parameterise the script and invoke it from galing?

Comment: @Viswanath, See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.x/#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder for docs about .!! This is just a code snippet.  You'll need to weave it into your own Gatling simulation...